# Gruntjs Livereload is watching but not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, livereload

Here's my Gruntfile.js http://pastebin.com/JZU5bbDk

and my package.json http://pastebin.com/umYsnWi1

I did `npm install` inside the main directory of my workspace (using WAMP) and it installed `node_modules` folder with a bunch of subfolders inside.

I went to the nodejs command prompt and went to the directory so `c:\wamp\www\thework` and typed `grunt watch` and I get

> Running "watch" task
>
> waiting....

and when I tried to change anything in any file in that folder ... I got nothing. It didn't notice.

Comment: Your `watch` command just reruns `watch.` What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: To auto-update the files on edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `watch` config doesn't make sense. Use this:

```
watch: {
    livereload: {
        options: { livereload: true },
        files: ['*.css']
    }
}
```

Running `watch` should now reload CSS files in the browser. From there you can expand out to other `watch` processes by adding other plugin tasks.